# How to create recurrings payments with paypal api

Tags: paypal

I'm working on implementing a payment system that requires the ability to set up recurring payments with an initial payment and a token for infinite recurring payments. However, I need to achieve this without relying on the subscription module. Specifically, I'm looking for a solution within the EU region.

Here are the key requirements:

Recurring Payments: I want to set up a recurring payment structure where the customer is billed periodically (e.g., monthly) for a specific amount.

Initial Payment: There should be an initial payment made at the start of the recurring payment agreement. This could be a one-time setup fee or the first installment of the recurring payments.

Infinite Recurring Payments: The recurring payments should continue indefinitely without a predetermined end date. The agreement should be flexible enough to allow the payments to be ongoing until canceled.

EU Region: The solution needs to comply with the regulations and standards of the European Union (EU) region.

I understand that PayPal provides a subscription module for handling recurring payments, but in this case, I'm looking for an alternative method that doesn't rely on that module. I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations on how to achieve this using the PayPal API or any other suitable approach within the EU region.

Thank you in advance for your help!

When I create an payment with the `/v1/payments/payment` I receive a payment token. But with this token I can execute the payment only once with the `/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}/execute` endpoint.

The api docs are very confusing. The `/v3/vault/payment-tokens` are only allowed in the US and the only alternative seems to be the subscription module, which is not what I am looking for.

Any idea?

Comment: Not familiar with that module's implementation, but PayPal Subscriptions (the product and API, not whatever 'module' you speak of) does meet the requirements in your question. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/

Comment: PayPal Subscriptions implementation forces you to manage the whole subscription interval, pricing model etc. inside PayPal, correct? I would like to manage the subscription recurrings on my own (inside Shopware) and use PayPal just for the payments. I am doing this already with Stripe. And in Shppware 5 the Abo Commerce Plugin does it the same.

Comment: With PayPal Subscriptions, PayPal handles the recurrence of payments according to what is set up and specified, yes. This can be done with the Subscriptions API.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

The PayPal Subscription Integration API [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/) is not confusing, just that you are not familiar with the big picture. Let's break it down.

### General Dev Workflow

#### Vendor

1. [Register & Login](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox) to Paypal sandbox account
2. Go to [Sandbox Account](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts) and get the business account information (email & password)
3. Go to [Plan Management](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans) (login using the business account)
4. Create Products (Give your product an ID)
5. Create Plans (PayPal will generate plan ID)
6. Integrate the [Paypal button in JS](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) by setting the  **Plan ID**
7. Setup **WebHook** to listen to PayPal events (e.g. receive a notification when a recurring payment is made)

#### Customer

1. Create Subscription (PayPal will generate a subscription ID)
2. Suspend (pause) Subscription
3. Cancel Subscription (cannot reactivate)

Basically, that's it.

### If you wish to integrate the API in PHP

You might need this [cURL-PHP converter](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/)

1. get **access token** from Paypal using your (client ID & secret ID)
2. setup cURL request header

   - `Content-Type: application/json` (sending the content as JSON)
   - `Accept: application/json`
   - `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`
3. setup your client URL (cURL)

   - get cURL at API documentation
   - convert cURL-PHP
   - tailor as you wish for cURL but for the **required** header, you must include
4. execute cURL
5. Listen to [PayPal HTTP response](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/responses)
6. Save data to your database

#### Extra

- look into `json_decode()` & `json_encode()` for PHP

You're welcome. If you need detail explanation, do let me know

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, even if my question was about the one solution without the subscription module. But for recurring payment tokens. But thanks to your answer I understand the paypal subscriptions even if I wasn't looking for it. Thanks

Comment: You're most welcome, because I was once confused by their documentation and I'm happy to share the knowledge. Why didn't I directly answer your query because from your question I knew you were unfamiliar with PayPal recurring APIs, therefore I try to deliver you the correct overview for it before you diving into the wrong rabbit hole. Welcome.

Comment: So is it possible to trigger recurring payments without triggering a subscription in PayPal? In the NVP/SOAP Api there is this DoReferenceTransaction method. But I would like to find a solution inside the rest API.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. It is because in PayPal, triggering recurring payments requires a "Subscription Agreement", unlike a one-time checkout payment.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment - it absolutely is confusing. Stripe is much more developer friendly.

Comment: Agreed. Stripe is easier to implement. But I'm just answering what's being asked. Good day.